# I need help finishing this 3 level dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dynamic, location

I know there are tons of other topics based on this subject.  My code is based on one of them. It works great. The only issue with it is that it's a 2 level dropdown. I need to add another dropdown so I can complete my Country, Region, City list.

If you can look at my code and advice me how to add the 3rd dropdown(cities), that would be wonderful.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script>
        function showHint(str) {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length==0) {
            document.getElementById("regiondiv").innerHTML="";
            return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("regiondiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?country="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  

    <div class="field">
        <label for="cat">Country</label>
        <select id="country" name="country" onChange="showHint(this.value);" required >

            <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>

            <?php  
                $getCountry = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM countries");

                if(!$getCountry->count()) {

                    echo 'No Country found!';

                } else {

                    foreach($getCountry->results() as $row) {

                        $country_id     =   escape($row->countryId);
                        $country_name   =   escape($row->countryName);

                 ?><option value="<?php echo $country_id; ?>" ><?php echo $country_name; ?></option><?php

                    }
                }
            ?>


        </select>

    </div>

    <label for="cat">Region</label>
    <div id="regiondiv">
        <select name="region" id="region">
        <option>--Select State--</option>
        <option></option>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php require_once 'core/init.php';

$country_id  =  escape(Input::get('country'));

$select_region = DB::getInstance()->get('regions', array('countryId', '=', $country_id));

    if(!$select_region->count()) {

        echo 'No Country found!';

    } else {

    ?><select name="region" id="region"><?php   

        foreach($select_region->results() as $row) {

            $region_id          =   escape($row->regionId);
            $region_name        =   escape($row->regionName);

        ?><option value="<?php echo $region_id; ?>" ><?php echo $region_name; ?></option><?php

        }
    ?></select><?php        
    }
```

Comment: Where will you be getting the city data from?

Comment: From mysql table, same as country and region.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific how this city table may look like? Got a region id associated with it? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem then? You are basically asking how to do exactly what you are doing now for the Regions again for Citys?

Like creating a cityAjax.php:

```
<?php require_once 'core/init.php';

$region_id  =  escape(Input::get('region'));

$select_city = DB::getInstance()->get('citys', array('regionId', '=', $region_id));

    if(!$select_city->count()) {

        echo 'No City found!';

    } else {

    ?><select name="city" id="city"><?php   

        foreach($select_city->results() as $row) {

            $city_id          =   escape($row->cityId);
            $city_name        =   escape($row->cityName);

        ?><option value="<?php echo $city_id; ?>" ><?php echo $city_name; ?></option><?php

        }
    ?></select><?php        
    }
```

I'm sorry, but your question doesn't really make sense...

---

**Update:**

Ah, I think I understand your problem. You don't understand how to let the generated regions selection load a city section.

Ok, you could do it like this:

- like mentioned further up, you would first need to create a new ajax.php for the logic of retrieving the cities. It would be nicer to handle all from one file, but to keep things simple we'll just go with a second php file.
- You will also need to extend your base html file and add a placeholder for the cities:

  ...
      Region
      
          
          --Select State--

  ```
  <label for="cat">Cities</label>
  <div id="citydiv">
      <select name="city" id="city">
      <option>--Select State--</option>
      <option></option>
  </div>
  ```

  ...
- You will also need to add a javascript function to populate this new placeholder:

:

```
function showHint(str) {   
    ...        
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?country="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    ...   
}

function showCity(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0) {
        document.getElementById("citydiv").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("citydiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cityAjax.php?region="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

:
- Last but not least, you will need to extend your existing ajax.php code, to call the new javascript function if a region is selected:

```
...
?><select name="region" id="region" onChange="showCity(this.value);" required><?php   

        foreach($select_region->results() as $row) {

            $region_id          =   escape($row->regionId);
            $region_name        =   escape($row->regionName);

        ?><option value="<?php echo $region_id; ?>" ><?php echo $region_name; ?></option><?php

        }
?></select><?php 
...
```

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: This helped a ton. Thank you so much! You got exactly what I was trying to ask.  For anyone else reading this, the only bit I would like to add is to not have any "<select>" tags in the #regiondiv and #citydiv on index.php. Have them only in the ajax.php.  That was one of the reasons it wasn't working.  But now it works 100%.