# Complicated situation. Getting input name from ajax select dropdown for mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dynamic, location

I have a locations dynamic dropdown (country,region,city) done with ajax. Works great.

My goal is to retrieve data (posts) from mysql table, based on the location selections.   I already have the posts in mysql table that correspond to the locations.

Now the issue I am having is that the query won't retrieve data based on the region and city. It will only work with the `$_GET`country. It comes to my understanding the reason is because region and city `<select>` queries are in a separate PHP files and are called through js code in the head section, so I am unable to use `$_GET` method to get their inputs.

Here is my form setup:

```
<form action="" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data >
    <div id="countrydiv">
        <select id="country" name="country" onChange="showRegion(this.value);">

            <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>

            <?php  
                $getCountry = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM countries");

                if(!$getCountry->count()) {

                    echo 'No Country found!';

                } else {

                    foreach($getCountry->results() as $row) {

                        $country_id     =   escape($row->countryId);
                        $country_name   =   escape($row->countryName);

                 ?><option value="<?php echo $country_id; ?>" ><?php echo $country_name; ?></option><?php

                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="regiondiv"></div>

    <div id="citydiv"></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>
```

I can get the country input name from above with this `$_GET['country']`, but I also need it for the region and city.  How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to make an AJAX request?

Comment: Nope. I already have ajax that does the multie level dropdown.  I need to retrive data from mysql table based on the locations I select from the dropdown.  It's just that I am unable to $_GET input of regiondiv and citydiv to work for some reason.

Comment: Where are you inputting data in those divs? I don't see any `<input>`s

Comment: Region inputs are in regionAjax.php and city inputs are in cityAjax.php.  They have the same query setup as you see above in the countrydiv. And they are called through js code.  Please see my previous topic here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888777/i-need-help-finishing-this-3-level-dynamic-dropdown

Comment: I have managed to solve this this issue. It was simple really. I just needed to do a lot of testing to get the right matching.  Thanks for your help anyways.